# TASK_WRITE_FAILED when trying to write on the table, Databricks (Scala)

Tags: scala, databricks

I have a code on Databricks (Scala) that constructs a df and the write it to a Database table. It is working fine for almost all of the tables, but there is a table with a problem. It says **No module named 'delta.connect' - TASK_WRITE_FAILED.**

In the penultimate cell I have

```
display(data)
```

An the data looks good
[image]

Then, in the last cell I have:

```
(
    data.write 
        .format("delta") 
        .mode("append") 
        .insertInto(targetTable)
)
```

[image]

The text of error is the following:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta.connect'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_MultiThreadedRendezvous                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1414, in SparkConnectClient._execute_and_fetch_as_iterator(self, req)
   1411 generator = ExecutePlanResponseReattachableIterator(
   1412     req, self._stub, self._retry_policy, self._builder.metadata()
   1413 )
-> 1414 for b in generator:
   1415     yield from handle_response(b)

File /usr/lib/python3.10/_collections_abc.py:330, in Generator.__next__(self)
    327 """Return the next item from the generator.
    328 When exhausted, raise StopIteration.
    329 """
--> 330 return self.send(None)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/reattach.py:131, in ExecutePlanResponseReattachableIterator.send(self, value)
    129 def send(self, value: Any) -> pb2.ExecutePlanResponse:
    130     # will trigger reattach in case the stream completed without result_complete
--> 131     if not self._has_next():
    132         raise StopIteration()

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/reattach.py:188, in ExecutePlanResponseReattachableIterator._has_next(self)
    187     self._release_all()
--> 188     raise e
    189 return False

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/reattach.py:160, in ExecutePlanResponseReattachableIterator._has_next(self)
    159 try:
--> 160     self._current = self._call_iter(
    161         lambda: next(self._iterator)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    162     )
    163 except StopIteration:

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/reattach.py:285, in ExecutePlanResponseReattachableIterator._call_iter(self, iter_fun)
    284         self._iterator = None
--> 285         raise e
    286 except Exception as e:
    287     # Remove the iterator, so that a new one will be created after retry.

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/reattach.py:267, in ExecutePlanResponseReattachableIterator._call_iter(self, iter_fun)
    266 try:
--> 267     return iter_fun()
    268 except grpc.RpcError as e:

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/reattach.py:161, in ExecutePlanResponseReattachableIterator._has_next.<locals>.<lambda>()
    159 try:
    160     self._current = self._call_iter(
--> 161         lambda: next(self._iterator)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    162     )
    163 except StopIteration:

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:426, in _Rendezvous.__next__(self)
    425 def __next__(self):
--> 426     return self._next()

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:826, in _MultiThreadedRendezvous._next(self)
    825 elif self._state.code is not None:
--> 826     raise self

_MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INTERNAL
    details = "Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2278.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2278.0 (TID 2473) (172.26.0.11 executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: [TASK_WRITE_FAILED] Task failed while writing rows to abfss://ucatalogwemetastore@azwesadbricksunitycatmst.dfs.core.windows.net/metastore/cddf9e6b-f8c2-4735-a50e-cabc613c06db/tables/58535ee1-b3c7-43d1-afbc-21efde623438.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.WriteFilesExec.$anonfun$doExecuteWrite$1(WriteFiles.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$computeOrReadCheckpoint$1(RDD.scala:410)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$5(Task.scala:146)
    at com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWith(UCSHandle..."
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer unix:/databricks/sparkconnect/grpc.sock {created_time:"2024-03-14T11:57:48.111777663+00:00", grpc_status:13, grpc_message:"Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2278.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2278.0 (TID 2473) (172.26.0.11 executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: [TASK_WRITE_FAILED] Task failed while writing rows to abfss://ucatalogwemetastore@azwesadbricksunitycatmst.dfs.core.windows.net/metastore/cddf9e6b-f8c2-4735-a50e-cabc613c06db/tables/58535ee1-b3c7-43d1-afbc-21efde623438.\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:927)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:551)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.WriteFilesExec.$anonfun$doExecuteWrite$1(WriteFiles.scala:116)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:934)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:934)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$computeOrReadCheckpoint$1(RDD.scala:410)\n\tat com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:407)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:374)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:82)\n\tat com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:82)\n\tat com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)\n\tat org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:196)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:181)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$5(Task.scala:146)\n\tat com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)\n\tat com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWith(UCSHandle..."}"
>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-2290610805725404>, line 5
      1 (
      2     data.write 
      3         .format("delta") 
      4         .mode("append") 
----> 5         .insertInto(targetTable)
      6 )

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/readwriter.py:660, in DataFrameWriter.insertInto(self, tableName, overwrite)
    658 self._write.table_name = tableName
    659 self._write.table_save_method = "insert_into"
--> 660 self._spark.client.execute_command(self._write.command(self._spark.client))

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1079, in SparkConnectClient.execute_command(self, command)
   1077     req.user_context.user_id = self._user_id
   1078 req.plan.command.CopyFrom(command)
-> 1079 data, _, _, _, properties = self._execute_and_fetch(req)
   1080 if data is not None:
   1081     return (data.to_pandas(), properties)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1441, in SparkConnectClient._execute_and_fetch(self, req, self_destruct)
   1438 schema: Optional[StructType] = None
   1439 properties: Dict[str, Any] = {}
-> 1441 for response in self._execute_and_fetch_as_iterator(req):
   1442     if isinstance(response, StructType):
   1443         schema = response

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1422, in SparkConnectClient._execute_and_fetch_as_iterator(self, req)
   1420                     yield from handle_response(b)
   1421 except Exception as error:
-> 1422     self._handle_error(error)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1706, in SparkConnectClient._handle_error(self, error)
   1693 """
   1694 Handle errors that occur during RPC calls.
   1695 
   (...)
   1703 Throws the appropriate internal Python exception.
   1704 """
   1705 if isinstance(error, grpc.RpcError):
-> 1706     self._handle_rpc_error(error)
   1707 elif isinstance(error, ValueError):
   1708     if "Cannot invoke RPC" in str(error) and "closed" in str(error):

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1742, in SparkConnectClient._handle_rpc_error(self, rpc_error)
   1740             info = error_details_pb2.ErrorInfo()
   1741             d.Unpack(info)
-> 1742             raise convert_exception(info, status.message) from None
   1744     raise SparkConnectGrpcException(status.message) from None
   1745 else:

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/connect.py:90, in convert_exception(info, message)
     84     return PythonException(
     85         "\n  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. "
     86         "Please see the stack trace below.\n%s" % message
     87     )
     89 # BEGIN-EDGE
---> 90 from delta.connect.exceptions import _convert_delta_exception
     92 delta_exception = _convert_delta_exception(info, message)
     93 if delta_exception is not None:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta.connect'
```

I am the owner of the table, so I don't think it is an error permission. Maybe of the capacity of the server?, because it says: TASK_WRITE_FAILED

If it helps, the original csv has 116 columns, and 3900 files (the rest of the tables doesn't have so many columns).
Maybe the number of columns is a problem?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciatte.

Thanks.

edit: I almost forgot, when constructing the data dataframe it conects to MongoDB to obtain the configuration of the table (delimiters, etc) and the name of the fileds